# networking: DNS settings ignored

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager, dns, static-ip

For several months, I have been successfully connected to the net via a static IP with my machine that is running ubuntu (16.04.3). I recently had to reinstall the OS, and now on the same machine, the system is ignoring my DNS settings. The DNS server hasn't changed, nor has the machine's static IP address changed. Furthermore, I can ping the DNS IP addresses with no problem from the ubuntu device. As a double check, other machines that I own and which reside on the same network have no trouble with DNS using the same addresses.

For the purpose of this discussion, assume the following hypothetical settings:

```
Hostname:    host-o-rama-bama.com
Static IP:   10.20.30.40
Gateway:     10.20.30.1
Netmask:     255.255.255.0
DNS server:  100.110.120.130
DNS server:  100.110.120.140
```

Using the Ubuntu Network Manager, I configured these settings as follows:

```
General
* Automatically connect to this network when it is available: Yes
* All users may connect to this network: Yes
Ethernet
* Device: enp2s0f1
* Wake on LAN: Default
802.1x security
(None)
DCB
(None)
IPV4 Settings
* Method: Manual
* Address:  10.20.30.40
* Netmask:  255.255.255.0
* Gateway:  10.20.30.1
* DNS Servers: 100.110.120.130,100.110.120.140
* Search Domains: host-o-rama-bama.com
IPV6 Settings
* Method: Ignore
```

After starting the network ...

```
# ifconfig
enp2s0f1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:fa:5b:4c:02:07  
          inet addr:10.20.30.40  Bcast:10.20.30.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::82fa:5bff:fe4c:207/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:63252 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:40966 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:53814860 (53.8 MB)  TX bytes:5441842 (5.4 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:7029 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7029 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:650606 (650.6 KB)  TX bytes:650606 (650.6 KB)
```

At this point, I can ping each of my DNS servers via their IP addresses.

Furthermore, remote sites can ping my ubuntu host both by its static IP address and also by the name `host-o-rama-bama.com`, which is already set up on the DNS servers. I can even ssh into my host both via its IP address and its DNS name.

However, I cannot see any domain names from the ubuntu machine, but , I can indeed access anywhere I want on the net via ssh, telnet, http, ping, etc. as long as I use the IP address.

In `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`, I put the following, and then I ran `resolvconf -u` ...

```
domain host-o-rama-bama.com
search host-o-rama-bama.com
nameserver 100.110.120.130
nameserver 100.110.120.140
```

However, after running it, the DNS is still not working.

I put the following into `/etc/network/interfaces` ...

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp2s0f1
iface enp2s0f1 inet static
address 10.20.30.40
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.20.30.1
dns-nameserver 100.110.120.130
dns-nameserver 100.110.120.140
dns-search host-o-rama-bama.com
```

I then did the following:

```
# ifdown enp2s0f1
# ifup enp2s0f1
```

Nothing changed. The DNS is still not working.

I then commented out everything in `/etc/network/interfaces` from the `auto enp2s0f1` line to the bottom of the file and then did this ...

```
# ifdown -a
# ifup -a
```

Still no DNS.

I then tried this ...

```
# /etc/init.d/network-manager stop
# /etc/init.d/network-manager start
```

The DNS is still not working.

Then, I did this:

```
# service networking restart
```

... and still no DNS.

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't use resolv.conf or interfaces because the dhcp configuration file overwrites them, and if there's an dns set up in your network manager configuration file it will over write dhcp

Comment: Does this tell us anything interesting? `sudo systemd-resolve --status`

Comment: @chili555 Did you mean `sudo systemd-resolve --statistics` by any chance? --status doesn't appear to be a valid switch.

Comment: @ElderGeek Ahhh! Quite correct. It *is* a valid switch in 18.04. OP is running 16.04.

Comment: How about: `sudo resolvconf -u` Is the symbolic link intact or broken?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the full dnsmasq package (On Ubuntu only dnsmasq-base is installed by default) : `sudo apt-get install dnsmasq`, then edit */etc/dnsmasq.conf* (add your DNS server : *server=8.8.8.8* for example). Restart dnsmasq and network manager services (`sudo service dnsmasq restart; sudo service network-manager restart`).

Hope this work.

Comment: Thank you, but it turns out that this `dnsmasq` suggestion didn't help. However, my problem seems to be moot now: I completely reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 from scratch, and now all is working. All I can guess is that perhaps I did something incorrectly in the previous release.

Answer (score 0):

I consider this question to be answered now. The `dnsmasq` suggestion is worthwhile, but the situation didn't get fixed until I completely reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 from scratch. My guess is that I did something during the original installation (??? not sure what) which prevented my DNS from working.

I need to remember that one possible solution to these kinds of seemingly intractable problems is: "Reinstall from scratch and try again." :)

Thanks to Eraseth and chili555 for all your help.

Excelsior! (Latin for "Onward and upward!")